# How to convert PX into DP in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Designer has given me a `PSD` file, He has created it for `1080X1920 resolution`

In PSD he defines that the `header` height should be `52px`, `Slider` height should be `350px` and so on..

In layout when i write `layout_height=350dp` its taking a lot of height and covering more than half of screen.

I am using default layout to accomplish this task.

Kindly guide me how to define `Height` in layout in `DP` with respect to `PX`

Comment: does not sound like a mobile design that can be properly translated. Things to tap on should be ~ 50 dp. Maybe that can help you figure a size out.

Comment: He defines this in `PX` for `1080X1920 resolution`. In `DP` it will have smaller value

Comment: what screen size is the definition for? As in physical width x height?

Comment: We are targeting `S5` device-  The resolution of `S5` is `1080X1920`
I am not using default layout to accomplish this

Comment: Assuming the desing is meant to be 1:1 scale on the device screen. Conversion factor for pixel to dp is, given the screen density = (160/density in dpi). The S5 has a 432 dpi screen, but is classified as xxhdpi which means it uses 480 dpi for calculations. That means for you that 1dp = 3 px on the screen in the end.

Comment: Thanks, i got that...but i am working in a default layout. How would android know that i am defining these `DP's` for  `1080X1920` or for `360X640` screen

Comment: It doesn't need to know because DP is device independant. Every device knows it's density. Once you set something to 100dp, a device will calculate how many pixels on it's screen that means. On (high-end) high density much more than on cheaper ones. But 100dp will always be around 2 fingers wide on any phone or tablet. You can think of dp as a unit similar to inch or cm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there's a lack of designer-developer flow. The designs you were given are not mobile friendly (Android neither iOS). I recommend you to take a look to a couple of tools for a nice workflow.

[Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com/)

[Zeplin](https://zeplin.io/)

And please read this article you both:

[Designer's guide to DPI](http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/)

In Android **you need to work in dps** and you need the designs to be given in dps. In case you are given the designs in pixels you have to have the agreement with the designer that 1px is equals to 1dp, in other words, the designer is working on [MDPI](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) basis where 1dp is equals to 1dp.

So the easiest way to go is your designer needs to work in a screen that is **360x640 pixels instead of 1080x1920**. Now you can forget about translating pixels to dps and the other way around because 1px would be 1dp for you. For your designer as well will be easier because he needs to go from [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) to the design tool, and he doesn't need to translate dps into pixels anymore. Everytime he reads 48 dps in the guidelines [(which is everywhere)](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/responsive-ui.html) he knows he has to read it as 48 pixels in his 360x640 canvas in the design tool.

Notes

360x640 is a common screen size in dps (Galaxy S5, Nexus 5 and many others) and because of that is taken as a reference now a days. Please realize **your designer can not give you the exact sizes for every component in every layout size for every device**. So things like the toolbar height (usually 56dp) is easy to translate to every device, but the toolbar width that you'll size in his designs (360 if you follow my recommendation) is completely useless for you, because that depends on the real device. The Galaxy S5 and the Nexus 5 are 360, but the Nexus 4 is 384, and the nexus 6, 6P and 5X is around 413.... [and actually there's much more!!](https://design.google.com/devices/)

Designing just for one device or one screen size is too simplistic and problematic. Be aware you have to develop [responsive](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-responsive-ui-in-android-7dc7e4efcbb3#.1a7x0uz3z) layouts ready for a [multiwindow](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/designing-for-multi-window.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.. 1 Question, I am working in a default layout, what exactly is the size of this default layout in terms of `DP` and `Pixels` ? Let say designer has design  for `360x640 pixels` but how would i manage this in layout ? I guess my `default Layout` does not know that i am working in for `360x640 pixels` screen

Comment: I'm assuming that by "default layout" you are talking about the default view in the preview panel in Android Studio. There is a default device selected in the top left corner of the preview layout in Android Studio but it changes with time and new devices. So in the past the default device was Nexus 4, then Nexus 5 and so on. Every time you change the device the dimensions change. Nexus 4 is 384x640 but Nexus 5 is 360x640, Nexus 6 is 411x731. Forget about fixed sizes, that's not how Android works.

If your designer gives you a 360x640 pixels design, you just take 1 pixel as 1 dp

Comment: That's what I meant when I told you it's never gonna happen the designer gives you the exact height/width of every component for every layout for every possible screen size because that's insane, there's no way to accomplish that. Instead of that, you'll have some fixed sizes (toolbars, margins, paddings, spacings according the Material Design guidelines, etc...) and you'll be using wrap_content or match_parent a lot as well.

Comment: Thnaks, what i am understanding from this is that, I have to use `Nexus 5- 360x640` screen when designing layout in `DP's, so that `20PX = 20DP`, and when user will open this in `1080X1920 screen`, android will multiply `DP's` by using its formula and stretch pixels accordingly.

Comment: That's too simple but it's a start. Please see my updated answer where I've included some links to responsive layouts and multiwindow.