# DP is display different layout in different screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created a layout and define following `Xml` in layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kirmani.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is filling my whole screen perfectly in `Nexus 4` screen. but when i preview all screens, its giving very weird look in some screens.

I am using `DP`, it should maintain same `display` according all screens, but it is not working like that. Kindly guide me..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd imageview width should be match parent. Like this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

instead of

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="405dp"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, This fits width across all devices, but height still an issue. In Nexus One it fills complete screen, but in other screens its showing space at the end –

Comment: You can use your height match parent in your 3rd imageview also

Answer (score 2):

Actually dp maintains same display according all screens. It's because every device are not supposed to be same width in dp. Some devices has 480dp, some of them 360dp etc.

If you want to your image fit your width, you must use

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

do not use fixed dp.

EDIT:

If you want to height fill up, use this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, This fits width across all devices, but height still an issue. In `Nexus One` it fills complete screen, but in other screens its showing space at the end

Answer (score 1):

We are talking Android ABC here. You need to understand how this works instead of looking for concrete answers to concrete problems, [as I already recommend you here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231539/how-to-convert-px-into-dp-in-layout/37231784#37231784).

**Every device has an specific dimension in DPs**. Nexus 4 is 384x640 but is the only one in your image with those dimensions. Please realize that is not that "is looking weird on some screens", in fact is gonna look weird on **all** screens that are not 384x640. For instance, the Nexus One in your image (which is 533dp x 320dp) is not working as expected, but is more difficult to realize because what is wrong is outside your view, but the views are bigger than the screen. Same with the Nexus S.

If you are trying to get a view from edge to edge (all the screen width), then use match_parent. Do not specify a size in DPs.

If you are trying to distribute views horizontally or vertically, please use an specific ViewGroup and/or weights, or you can use the [Percent Support Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#percent) for doing things like [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html). [Take a look at this tutorial for more](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en).

Anyway, here you have your copy&paste code.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.6"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks again :) You are using `height=0` and using `weight` that adds `Height`, Can you elaborate the difference between `weight & height`. As with `weight` i am able to add any number of `Views` but with `height` it adds only certain number of `Views` and starts hiding some `views` in small screens.

Comment: Just go and do some learning by reading and doing. Don't use StackOverflow to learn, just to solve problems after you've read and tried several times but you are still failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, My problem is solved now. You are right, Reading the whole thing completely helped ! :)